# Calculating a modified version of integral representation of the Hankel's function of the first kind

Tags: special-functions, complex-integration

Firstly I have put all the formula together:

[All of the following formulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa1Ne.png)

Considering that the Hankel function of the first kind can be expressed as follows:

[Hankel function of the first kind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFqZX.png)

in which the path of integration is from -Infinity to 0 then zero to PI*i then from PI*i to PI*i+Infinity.

How can I calculate the following integral on the same path:

[Integral to be calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twRXQ.png)

where:

[definition of A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8jdL.png)

and:

[definition of Delta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guyhD.png)

Sorry for the pictures. I do not know how to use MathJax.

Comment: Maybe try to paste the images here so it is easier to see all together? I understand that it is a pain to rewrite everything, but in the future, try to use MathJax :) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have put all the formulation together in one picture. @TerezaTizkova